# (Also roblox related)Countdown freezes at a random number

Tags: roblox

so there are 2 scripts: script and localscript.

The script determines how many seconds there will be and then it fires it to all player clients & the localscript changes the text to seconds. But when i tested the game the countdow freezes either at a number or a random number anyway here's the script again:

script:

```
local ReplicatedStorage = game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage")


local remoteEvent = ReplicatedStorage:WaitForChild("IntermissonEvent")

local secondsRemaining = 15

for t = secondsRemaining, 0, -1 do
    remoteEvent:FireAllClients(t)
    wait(1)
end
```

localscript:

```
local ReplicatedStorage = game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage")

local remoteEvent = ReplicatedStorage:WaitForChild("IntermissonEvent")

local function onTimerUpdate(seconds)
    script.Parent.Text =(seconds)
    wait(15)
    script.Parent.Parent.CountdownText.Visible = false
    script.Parent.Parent.IntermissionText.Visible = false
    script.Parent.Parent.TextLabel.Text ="Vote for a Map!"
    script.Parent.Parent.MapVotingFrame.Visible = true
    end

remoteEvent.OnClientEvent:Connect(onTimerUpdate)
```

Comment: Does it consistently freeze on the same number?

Comment: it can freeze at a number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your LocalScript is running all of this logic every single time the server fires the event. Instead of waiting, check the value with an if-then.

```
local function onTimerUpdate(seconds)
    script.Parent.Text = tostring(seconds)

    if seconds == 0 then
        script.Parent.Parent.CountdownText.Visible = false
        script.Parent.Parent.IntermissionText.Visible = false
        script.Parent.Parent.TextLabel.Text = "Vote for a Map!"
        script.Parent.Parent.MapVotingFrame.Visible = true
    end
end
```

Comment: Heyo @GameBuilderLol, I'm glad to hear that! Could you please mark this as the accepted answer.

Comment: hahaha oh no, then it seems your problem lies somewhere else. Maybe this isn't the answer then.

Comment: actually i needed that answer, what im talking about is the countdown freezing at a number the notable numbers that froze are 22,20,19,18, & 12.(I changed the secondsRemaining to 35).

Comment: So as it is counting down, everything is fine. But the countdown will freeze on a few numbers here and there but will still keep going? Or does the countdown freeze and not get any further?

Comment: it will freeze but eventually it will get going

Comment: ok it's like this: the countdown will obviously countdown until it hits at 19 then that's one of the numbers that will freeze eventually it will countdown to 18 but then it froze again eventually the countdown will continue till it reaches 0.(yeah im not good at describing problems of my game).